# Setting up cascading deletes from multiple parent entities to child entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 7 in combination with postgres and want to configure the following situation but i cannot get this working correctly.

I have the table Customer and the table Supplier that can both have multiple addresses in the table Address.

Both the Customer and Supplier Classes have have a list of addresses as follow:

```
private readonly List<Address> _addresses = new List<Address>();
public virtual IReadOnlyList<Address> Addresses => _addresses.ToList();
```

Removing an addres should be doen via the Customer or Supplier with the RemoveAddress method which in turn can access the private address field.

The configuration for Customer and Supplier is as follow:

```
internal class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Customer));
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Addresses).WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent?.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}

internal class SupplierConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Supplier>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Supplier> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(Supplier));
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Addresses).WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .Metadata.PrincipalToDependent?.SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

This generates the following migration script which seems correct.

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Address",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
            CustomerId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true),
            SupplierId = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Address", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Address_Customer_CustomerId",
                column: x => x.CustomerId,
                principalTable: "Customer",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Address_Supplier_SupplierId",
                column: x => x.SupplierId,
                principalTable: "Supplier",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });
```

When i apply this configuration to the database it does not seem to delete the address records when calling the remove method on Customer and Supplier. It only sets the CustomerId or SupplierId column in the table Address to null.

What am i doing wrong here?

Here is the logic for the remove method of the Customer and Supplier Classes.

```
public void RemoveAddress(int id)
{
    var address = _addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    if (address != null)
    {
        _addresses.Remove(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what your `remove` method do,  `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` means when you delete  principal entity(Customer,Supplier), dependent entity(Address) will also be deleted.

Comment: `nullable: true` in migration for `CustomerId` and `SupplierId` look suspicious, normally they should be `false`. Can you show the relevant part of the model classes? Also do you have NRT enabled?

Comment: @XinranShen Currently the remove only removes the relationship. I could remove the address by calling the Remove method on the DbContext but this would ga against the DDD principle. De Aggregate should not be concerned of database concerns. It would be nice if entity framework can be configured in a way that it would not only delete the relationship but also remove the entity from the database. I could of cource implement some logic mark the address entities as removed in the saveChanges method of the dbcontext but it would be nicer if it would work out of the box.

Comment: @IvanStoev 
CustomerId and SupplierId must be nullable because an address does not have to belong to both a customer and a supplier.

Yes i have NRT enabled.
I have added the logic for the remove method to my description above

Comment: @Gabe Got it. Mutually exclusive "parents" / "owners". Logically required, but physically optional on the database table. Still, the problem (probably EFC bug) is from that design, since what you are describing is the behavior (what they call [Severing a relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#severing-a-relationship) for optional relationships.

Comment: Hi Ivan. I think this is an architecture thing that should be addressed by for example adding a marker field in the classes that should be deleted. Then before saving the changes to the database we can check the entities that are marked for deletion and set the entity to be deleted in the context. 

After reading the following article that i found, i reconsidered hard deletes and do soft deletes now.
https://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/